# Where do I get the old OpenVPN GUI v11.13.0.0

Tags: openvpn, tap

I have an open VPN GUI v11.13 which works perfectly on my Windows 10 laptop.
Such that I can just move the client.conf, *.crt and *.key from my Ubuntu PC to the Windows 10 laptop openVpn folder and just simply connect and it just works.
Unfortunately, I don't have the installer.

However recently I cannot seem to find this same version anywhere, not to mention that the new version that I downloaded from the OpenVPN website gives me an error while importing the client.conf

**Failed to import profile ... TAP mode is not supported**

Where can I get the same OpenVPN GUI v11.13?

Comment: I have exactly this error in openVPN to iphone. I work with the "Remmina Software" on Ubuntu, and that's ok.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the installed GUI exe shows **v11.13** in the About section.
But in the **Windows Control Panel** shows **2.4.7-I607**.

These old versions like *(openvpn-install-2.4.7-I607-Win10.exe)* are available in this link
[OpenVPN ol Releases](https://build.openvpn.net/downloads/releases/)